# MATLAB: Using Neopixel Library for Arduino Uno R3 to control LED inside loop

Tags: matlab, arduino, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm using MATLAB to control a neopixel LED strip and I'm getting some weird behavior and I'm not sure what the issue could be. I have the following two functions:

```matlab
function flicker(neostrip, ledNum, sec)
    if any(neostrip.readColor(ledNum))
        writeColor(neostrip, ledNum, [1 1 1]);
        delay(sec);
    else
        writeColor(neostrip, ledNum, [0 0 0]);
        delay(sec);
    end
end

function delay(seconds)
    % function pause the program
    % seconds = delay time in seconds
    tic;
    while toc < seconds
    end
end
```

I already have a Neopixel object called `neostrip` and I am able to control the Neopixel LEDs using `writeColor(neostrip, 1, [1 1 1]);` from the command line, but when I run my `flicker()` function the on-board Arduino LED flickers rather than my Neopixel LEDs.

Any ideas? The `writeColor()` function seems to work just fine outside of my `flicker()` function, so I'm not sure where my issue comes from. I thought there could be an issue with passing by value or reference, but I'm not sure why the code suddenly executes on the Arduino built-in LED when `writeColor()` is called inside my function.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this was actually a really stupid oversight on my part. The issue was that my function was set to turn on an LED if it was on and turn off an LED if it was off, resulting in not change in behavior. 
I'm not sure why the Arduino LED was flickering, but at least I got it fixed by switching the `[1 1 1]` and `[0 0 0]` matrices.